# C daemon sleep()

Tags: c, daemon, sleep

I'm running a running a simple daemon test in c++. It runs fine without the sleep() but if I add sleep() func it runs once then stays a sleep. Further the first run should print once "Hello" in logs/log.dat file but that doesn't happen either. Here is the code:

```
 #include <cstdlib>  
 #include <cstdio>  
 #include <iostream>  
 #include <unistd.h>  
 using namespace std;  
 int main(int argc, char** argv) {  
    FILE *f = NULL;   
    if ((f = fopen("logs/log.dat  ", "w")) != NULL) {  
        if (daemon(0, 0) >= 0) {  
            while (true) {  
                fprintf(f, "%s\n", "Hello");  
                sleep(5);  
            }  
        } else {  
            fprintf(f, "%s\n", "Error detaching terminal");  
        }  
    } else {  
        printf("%s\n", "Cannot open log file");  
    }  
    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: To format code on SO, select it and click the `101010` button.

Comment: Be careful of the spaces on the file name. Some file systems those are significant.

Comment: @Martin: if it isn't C++, which language is it.  It takes some macro trickery to make the '`using namespace std;`' work as C code, and the header names are unorthodox for C too - but that is all usual for C++.  Granted, the code could be written as C if the material before `main()` was cleaned up.

Comment: @Jonathan: Does it really do anything. It is only required because the OP is using the C++ versions of the header files. There is no part of the above that is C++ it is solely C. And by marking the problem as C we get a whole group of people that are much better at using the above functionality than C++ users (Who will not be quite as familiar with the above as C experts).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding fflush() after your fprintf(). It might be working but just has not written the data to the disk yet.

Comment: Also closing the file before ending the program is good form.

Comment: @Greg: the program doesn't terminate.

Answer (score 3):

What is in the `daemon()` function?  In particular, does it close open files other than standard input, standard output and standard error?  If so, then the subsequent `fprintf()` statements fail because the file that was opened before you called `daemon()` is closed afterwards.

If your code tested the return values from the printing functions, you would be able to find this out (though you'd probably have to open a log file with an absolute pathname to be able to report it from the daemonized process).

The quickest way to check this hypothesis may be to open the log file after daemonizing.

Note that some `daemon()` routines change directory too - typically to the root directory.  That would give you a headache with the relative path to the log file.

---

On MacOS X, the `daemon(3)` function is provided with a declaration in `<stdlib.h>`; it was introduced in BSD 4.4, it seems:

> #### SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
> #include <stdlib.h>
>
>  int
>  daemon(int nochdir, int noclose);
> ```
>
> #### DESCRIPTION
>
> The daemon() function is for programs wishing to detach themselves from the controlling terminal and
>        run in the background as system daemons. [...]
>
> Unless the argument nochdir is non-zero, daemon() changes the current working directory to the root (/).
>
> Unless the argument noclose is non-zero, daemon() will redirect standard input, standard output, and standard error to /dev/null.

---

You can inspect the [FreeBSD 8](http://svn.freebsd.org/viewvc/base/stable/8/lib/libc/gen/daemon.c?revision=196045&view=markup) source code.

Since the call to `daemon()` passes 0 twice, the code does do a `chdir("/")` and it reconnects file descriptors 0, 1, 2 to '/dev/null'.  The manual page goes on to discuss `fork(2)` and `setsid(2)`.  So, we can be moderately confident that your program has its standard I/O channels reconnected to /dev/null, and the current directory changed to the root directory.

The man page does mention that you should be careful to ensure that any opened files have a file descriptor greater than 2 to avoid issues.  Can you print 'fileno(f)' somewhere - it is an integer - and ensure that it is greater than 2.  If it is not big enough, then that is the cause of your trouble; don't invoke your program with any of stdin, stdout or stderr already closed.

That doesn't yet explain the absence of data from the file, nor why `sleep()` affects the result.  Of course, the classic implementation of `sleep()` fiddles with signals and SIGALRM; the man page for `daemon(3)` mentions SIGHUP. However, the FreeBSD 8 implementation of `sleep(3)` uses the `nanosleep(2)` system call.

So, I'm going to agree with Jay's suggestion - the file will be fully buffered and you have to wait for a large number of 5-second cycles to print enough data to flush the buffer (that might need 4096 bytes, at 6 bytes per 5 seconds, will require about an hour to produce anything in the file).  Adding `fflush()` is most likely to fix the 'non-appearance of message' issue.  Alternatively, use `setvbuf(f, 0, _IONBF, 0);` to turn off all buffering, or `setvbuf(f, 0, _IOLBF, BUFSIZ);` to enable line buffering.  And `sleep()` is a factor simply because it slows the processing down so much.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but because I used syslog, using fflush() wasn't possible.
In my case the solution was to change debug message.

From:

```
syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "DEBUG: tick");
```

To:

```
syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "DEBUG: tick %d", i); // i is increased in the loop
```

So that there was every time different message.